# ActionMailer mail function with syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, actionmailer

I get the following syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
```

Here is the ActionMailer code, which I have proofread multiple times:

```
def signup_confirmation(user, account, log)
   @user = user
   mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Confirmation Email")
end 

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587, 
    domain: "domain.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

EDIT: error trace from the tests:

1) UserMailer signup_confirmation renders the headers
     Failure/Error: let(:mail) { UserMailer.signup_confirmation }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)
     # ./app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:9:in `signup_confirmation'
     # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:5:in`block (3 levels) in '
     # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in '

2) UserMailer signup_confirmation renders the body
     Failure/Error: let(:mail) { UserMailer.signup_confirmation }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)
     # ./app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:9:in `signup_confirmation'
     # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:5:in`block (3 levels) in '
     # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in '

Any help would be appreciated. I've followed the code from the railscasts.

Comment: Your application log would be useful here.

Comment: What does your error say? Can you post the error trace? Thanks.

Comment: Updated with error trace.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a host config in my environ:

# Specify what domain to use for mailer URLs
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "localhost:3000"}